# Not able to list Unity Catalog databases and tables in Azure Databricks Delta Connectivity

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I have a delta table as part of the Unity Catalog when I try to query in Azure Databricks Delta Lake I am not able to list it on the table. It is only listed on Hive metastore not for Unity Catalog.

In Azure Data Factory pipelines, I created a copy data function to copy data from ADLS to the Azure Databricks Delta Lake table. I am not able to find that table which I have created in Unity Catalog, it is only listing tables from Hive Metastore. Help me with this!

Answer (score 2):

> **If you want to list Unity Catalog databases and table.**

**Try this code :**

```
db = spark.catalog.listDatabases()
for database1 in db:
    print("database_name:", database1.name)

    spark.catalog.setCurrentDatabase(database1.name)
    
    tables = spark.catalog.listTables()
    for table in tables:
        print("table_name:", table.name)
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Or**

> **In SQL.**

**Syntax:**

```
%sql
SHOW  TABLES  IN `unity_catalog`.`database`;
```

[image]